# Reference for Codimension in Infinite Dimensional Normed vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request

There are a couple identities I would like to use related to the codimension and its relationship to the annihilator; some of these seem to be true for all normed vector spaces, and others seem only to hold when the underlying space is reflexive.

Examples of what I'm looking for references for: let $X$ be any vector space, $V \subset X$ a subspace. If you define $codim V = dim (X / V)$ for a subspace $V$, then because $(X/V)^*$ is isomorphic to $V^{\circ} = \{l \in X^* \mid l(v) = 0 \;\;\forall v \in V\}$. As a consequence, $dim(X / V) = dim V^{\circ} = codim V$ in all cases, regardless of the presence of any norm. The situation is the same when we have a norm, $V$ is presumed closed, and $X^*$ is now the space of bounded linear functionals.

On the other hand, I think that $codim T = dim {}^{\circ} T$ for any $T \subset X^*$ only if we take $T$ closed and $X$ reflexive, where ${}^{\circ} T$ is the intersection of all kernels of $t \in T$.

I'm only looking for a reference; the proofs of all these seem to be straightforward, but I'm worried about fundamental errors I might have made, and it would be nice if I could check my work and make sure the statements I'm using are the strongest possible.